# The variable 'a' is of a reference type, and 'A' is a custom class. When the value of 'a' is null, why does 'a is A' result in true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, typechecking

**Updated：Those code was written in Unity, and Unity has overrided "==" operator and even the 'null'. That's the background.**

---

[image]

Text version:

```
    var mirr = RecursedManager.instance.currentEntrance;

    if (mirr == null)
    {
        if (mirr is BoxExit)
        {
            var a = 1;// Even without debug mode, this line will be executed, if I use "print(1)" instead.

        }


    }
```

The image above is a screenshot taken while debugging in C#. It shows the execution reaching the line 'var a = 1'. **Since it has reached this line, it indicates that both conditions 'mirr == null' and 'mirr is BoxExit' are true simultaneously. I don't understand why a null value can be judged as a subclass of the 'BoxExit' class**.

I've heard an explanation that "variables contain type information, whereas null does not." This conclusion was also my initial reaction. However, I provided a simple example that seems to contradict this reasoning. For instance:

```
string aa = null;
bool b = aa is string;
print(b); // The output of b is false
```

Finally, some additional information (regarding the definition of 'currentEntrance', unsure if it's needed):

```
public IEntrance currentEntrance { get => _instance._currentEntrance; set => _instance._currentEntrance = value; }


private IEntrance _currentEntrance;
```

Where 'BoxExit' is a custom class I've defined, inheriting from Unity's 'MonoBehaviour' class. Additionally, the 'BoxExit' class implements the 'IEntrance' interface.

Comment: `null` is a possible value for any reference type. You can assign it to any reference-typed variable. If you used `if (mirr is BoxExit x)` on the other hand you'd be using a pattern match that checks that `mirr` is an actual non-null value of `BoxExit`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X4x9nB) ... I think it may show like this in debugger if information in pdb differes from code in IDE

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xzi1mv

Comment: Does your BoxExit class override the `==` operator? That [could explain](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sW9NyW) this behavior. Otherwise, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Selvin That's indeed strange! I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, and every time I debug, mirr is BoxExit always evaluates to true. I'm not sure why there would be a difference on different platforms.

Comment: @Heinzi You are right!!It was overrided!! I am using Unity, and the operation == was overrided by the engine!

Comment: Can you say what does Unity do in their overridden == operator?

Comment: @vainquit: Ah, perfect. I extended my comment into an answer, so that you can mark the question as answered, if you with to do so. (To be precise, I undeleted the answer I had already written before I decided that a comment would be more appropriate for guesswork.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know anything about the type of `mirr`, so we can only guess, but it's certainly possible for C# classes to override the `==` operator.

The following example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sW9NyW)) will output `True` twice:

```
using System;

S s = new S();
Console.WriteLine(s == null);
Console.WriteLine(s is S);

class S
{
    public static bool operator==(S s1, S s2) => true;
    public static bool operator!=(S s1, S s2) => false;
}
```